# I want to use fragment method in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragment which is associated with the viewpager .
All three fragments are working fine but as now I want to use fragment methods in my extends AppcompactActivity 
how can I use that .
my fragments don't have i.d like fm.findviewbyid(R.id.myfragment)

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get Current fragment position from `viewpager.getCurrentItem()`.

```
int pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();    
Fragment activeFragment = adapter.getItem(pos);
if(activeFragment instanceof Fragment1) {
    ((Fragment1)activeFragment).callMethod();
}
```